# What's the opposite of primitive?

Tags: data-types

In java, `int`, `byte` and `boolean` are primitives, while `String` is not.

This can be contrasted with c where `string` is a primitive (essentially an array of `char`s).

What is the term for types that aren't primitive?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: C does not use the term primitive. A C string is a [*derived type*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type), comprised of a *basic type*

Comment: In Java, everything that's not a primitive type is a reference type: "There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types (§4.2) and reference types (§4.3)." [JLS paragraph 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most general term (language agnostic) is a [composite data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type).

In Java there are several types of composite data type, the most obvious is a Class but an Enum would be another example.

A boxed type is another related term, which is a primitive wrapped in a class to provide an object oriented interface. Examples of this in Java are an `int` vs. an `Integer` or a `char` vs. a `Character`.

> In java, int, byte and boolean are primitives, while String is not.

A `String` is actually a boxed type. Under the hood it's implemented as a char array just like C and you could use a char array too if you wanted. Obviously most people don't do this as you won't have any of the convenient abstractions provided by the `String` class.

Here's how the [java.lang.String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#113) class is implemented in openjdk:

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];
```

As you can see, there's nothing special about a string in Java.

Comment: Depending on the language, there may be abstract non-primitive datatypes that aren't composite (the implementation uses a primitive type, but the type system ensures you can't rely on that.) Additionally, wrapped primitive types are only "composite" in a rather degenerate way. The best way to describe the opposite is primitive is probably just "non-primitive", or perhaps "user-defined".

Comment: I don't think you can consider String a boxed type, since the underlying character array is actually a reference type. In C# though you can consider it a boxes type, I believe, because it wraps a pointer to a character array.

Answer (score 2):

#### Composite Data Types (CDTs)

One answer to this question may be CDTs, but I don't think that is a general enough response. CDTs only account for a subset of non-primitive types: the definition of CDTs does not account for types that include methods. In fact, CDT is further misleading as they are expected to aggregate data, i.e., include fields. *It is not a requirement for non-primitives to have fields*.

#### User Defined Types (UDT)

There are ample examples of non-primitive non-UDTs, e.g., String in Java.

#### Reference Types

This doesn't help either. Consider that a pointer in C may point to anything, including primitive types.

#### Summary

As far as I am aware there is no general term for non-primitive types. Maybe except, as mentioned by @Doval, "non-primitive type".